# Drupal 7 Webform Components Related To Individual Nodes

Tags: 7, nodes, webforms, entities

I am attempting to create a decision making "questionnaire" in Drupal 7. I am currently using the Webform module to create the questionnaire.

The questionnaire (webform) will create a list of related nodes based on the users submission. What I need is a way to relate the nodes to the webform components.

For example, if a user selects 'Coffee Shop' & 'Sandwiches' on one of the multiple choice questions, all nodes relating to 'Coffee Shops' & 'Sandwiches' will be added to the list.

Is there an available module that will allow me to relate webform components to nodes or would I some how incorporate taxonomies into this for the relationships?

Would EntityForm be a better module for this type of thing?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what UX you want, but with [Fieldgroups](http://drupal.org/project/field_group) webforms can be multi-paged. As of webform 4.x [Conditional Fields](http://drupal.org/project/webform_conditional) (on the same page, or across pages) is supported by webform. You can have hidden fields already in webform if you need a simple storage mechanism not seen by users ...

I imagine you could then use [webform rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_rules) and upon final submission of the webform to examine whatever values have been submitted and use a custom rule to populate an available list of NIDs based on the submitted criteria.

You could maybe use [Entity List](https://www.drupal.org/project/entitylist) and [nodequeues](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodequeue) to solve this:

- if component is selected on submission use Entity List X, which references a smart nodequeue to nodes of a certain content type ... etc.

Comment: I like where you're going with this. It sounds like it could work with some configuration. I've decided to give it a try with the EntityForm module & FieldGroups. It seems EntityForm is a better choice because it allows me to add Fields used in the form to a node type. I will report back with my final solution.